# throws org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException while logging in to XMPP server using JMeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter, xmpp, jmeter-plugins, openfire

I am trying to log into a local OpenFire XMPP server through JMeter. I was able to connect but am unable to login as it throws the following Exception from jmeter.log file:

`2023-01-16 23:53:07,371 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 2023-01-16 23:53:07,371 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 2023-01-16 23:53:07,373 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*) 2023-01-16 23:53:07,414 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 2023-01-16 23:53:07,415 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 2023-01-16 23:53:07,415 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 2023-01-16 23:53:07,415 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false 2023-01-16 23:53:07,424 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 2023-01-16 23:53:07,424 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 2023-01-16 23:53:07,424 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 2023-01-16 23:54:47,532 ERROR c.b.j.x.JMeterXMPPSampler: Error in XMPP Sampler:  org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: null at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:191) ~[smack-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7] at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:175) ~[smack-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7] at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.bindResourceAndEstablishSession(XMPPConnection.java:535) ~[smack-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7] at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.login(XMPPTCPConnection.java:260) ~[smack-tcp-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7] at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.actions.Login.perform(Login.java:51) ~[jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?] at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.JMeterXMPPSampler.sample(JMeterXMPPSampler.java:57) ~[jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?] 2023-01-16 23:54:48,447 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 2023-01-16 23:54:48,447 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 2023-01-16 23:54:48,447 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 2023-01-16 23:54:48,447 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)`

I have done debugging and realised that JMeter during the authentication uses STARTTLS, however the local Openfire xmpp server that I am using is http and doesn't use SSL. I have tried disabling SSL by adding **server.rmi.ssl.disable=true** to my jmeter.properties file, yet it still uses STARTTLS during authentication. How can I change it to SASL?
If anyone have faced the same issue and resolved it or have any solution for my problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think SASL is supported as of XMPP Plugin version 1.5.1, the options are in:

- you either need to amend the [plugin source code](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/tree/master/xmpp) yourself accordingly
- or if you're a BlazeMeter customer you can request functionality implementation via raising a [BlazeMeter Support ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)
- or you can write your own authentication logic in a [JSR223 component](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and replace the connection created by the `bzm - XMPP Connection` with your own instance

Comment: Thank you, I went with the first option. The code changes for the SASL support have already been made 5 years ago, but they haven't released that XMPP Protocol support version yet, so I cloned the project, built it and copied the jar files to the lib/ext folder of my jmeter and restarted my jmeter. My test plan is working as expected now.